# How can I travel to Mexico by air?

Tags: visas, air-travel, mexico, italian-residents, iraqi-citizens

I hold an Iraqi passport with an Italian resident permit (ASILO). I want to travel to Mexico. Do I need a visa or can I travel without a visa?

Comment: Put your exact details into https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm and it will tell you what you need. As an Iraqi citizen it could be difficult to fly through the US, so I would look for flights avoiding this.  Your best choices for entry airports are probably Mexico City and Cancun.

Answer (score 1):

As a permanent resident of a Schengen Country, you can get a visa on arrival in Mexico regardless of citizenship. (https://www.gob.mx/inm/documentos/paises-y-regiones-que-requieren-visa-para-viajar-a-mexico)

Comment: @KamaranAziz  It's not clear than an Italian ASILO confers status as a "Permanent Resdient" as required for a Mexico visa on arrival. ASILO has a five-year term, although it can be renewed. Does this qualify as "permanent" ? I don't know.